# Will upgrading to Windows 10 break my dual-boot setup?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

My computer has a dual-boot setup, with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. Once I will get the free upgrade, will that do something to my dual-boot setup? (And if so, can I restore it easily?)

Comment: Maybe helpful - http://askubuntu.com/questions/576590/if-windows-10-upgrade-affects-grub2-and-screws-up-my-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-wil

Answer (score 2):

Most times YES. You will have to repair your bootloader.

After you upgrade Windows, using a bootable Ubuntu USB or CD

Run it -> Install and run 'Boot repair' -> Recommended Repair

and reboot the system.

hope this will help you if you get problems.